# Why is my node js code able to POST a login form to be matched from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using node.js I already can post from a signup html page. However the code below

```
exports.login = function (req, res, next) {


if (req.body && req.body.email && req.body.password)  {

    var userLogin = new User ({

        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    userLogin.findOne(function(err) {
        if (!err) {
            res.redirect('/about.html');
        } else {
            res.redirect('http://google.com');
            next(err);
        }
    });
} else {
    next(new Error('Incorrect POST'));
}
```

};

The problem I am having is that the userLogin.findOne is not working as it says findOne is undefined.

The model.js file that this is linking to is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;
 // these values can be whatever you want - we're defaulting to a
// max of 5 attempts, resulting in a 2 hour lock
MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 5,
LOCK_TIME = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;



var UserSchema = new Schema({ 
email: { type: String, required: true, lowercase:true, index: { unique: true } },
password: { type: String, required: true },
firstName: {type: String, required: true},
lastName: {type: String, required: true},
phone: {type: Number, required: true},
birthday: {type: Date, required: true},


loginAttempts: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
lockUntil: { type: Number }

});

UserSchema.virtual('isLocked').get(function() {
// check for a future lockUntil timestamp
return !!(this.lockUntil && this.lockUntil > Date.now());
});


//password hashing middleware

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
var user = this;

// only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
// generate a salt
bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    // hash the password along with our new salt
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});    
});
//password verification

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
});
};


UserSchema.methods.incLoginAttempts = function(cb) {
// if we have a previous lock that has expired, restart at 1
if (this.lockUntil && this.lockUntil < Date.now()) {
    return this.update({
        $set: { loginAttempts: 1 },
        $unset: { lockUntil: 1 }
    }, cb);
}
// otherwise we're incrementing
var updates = { $inc: { loginAttempts: 1 } };
// lock the account if we've reached max attempts and it's not locked already
if (this.loginAttempts + 1 >= MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS && !this.isLocked) {
    updates.$set = { lockUntil: Date.now() + LOCK_TIME };
}
return this.update(updates, cb);
};

// expose enum on the model, and provide an internal convenience reference 
var reasons = UserSchema.statics.failedLogin = {
NOT_FOUND: 0,
PASSWORD_INCORRECT: 1,
MAX_ATTEMPTS: 2
};

UserSchema.statics.getAuthenticated = function(email, password, cb) {
this.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    // make sure the user exists
    if (!user) {
        return cb(null, null, reasons.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    // check if the account is currently locked
    if (user.isLocked) {
        // just increment login attempts if account is already locked
        return user.incLoginAttempts(function(err) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            return cb(null, null, reasons.MAX_ATTEMPTS);
        });
    }

    // test for a matching password
    user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);

        // check if the password was a match
        if (isMatch) {
            // if there's no lock or failed attempts, just return the user
            if (!user.loginAttempts && !user.lockUntil) return cb(null, user);
            // reset attempts and lock info
            var updates = {
                $set: { loginAttempts: 0 },
                $unset: { lockUntil: 1 }
            };
            return user.update(updates, function(err) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
                return cb(null, user);
            });
        }

        // password is incorrect, so increment login attempts before responding
        user.incLoginAttempts(function(err) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            return cb(null, null, reasons.PASSWORD_INCORRECT);
        });
    });
});
};




module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: can you post the code of the class "User" ?

Comment: var User = require('../user-model.js'); which is the file with the UserSchema

Comment: The answer Matt gave works but it does not authenticate the login and just logs in with redirecting to the correct page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `userLogin` is an instance of the User model which means you've created a [document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html).  As documentation for [mongoose queries](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) states, queries are handled using 'static helper methods' which means they aren't available on an instance of a model (i.e. on a document).

I think you'd probably want your code to look more like this where `userLogin` is an object that holds your conditions for the query and then you could use the `User` model's `.findOne` method to execute the query.

```
var userLogin = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
};

User.findOne(userLogin, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        res.redirect('/about.html');
    } else {
        res.redirect('http://google.com');
        next(err);
    }
});
```

**Edit:** OK, so the above answered the question about why findOne was undefined.

The second question asked is "why doesn't this authenticate the user?"

The reason the code is redirecting to (I assume) the '/about.html' page is because that's exactly what the code does...as written.

To authenticate (and we're technically starting a new answer to an originally unasked question): you need to call the `UserSchema.statics.getAuthenticated` method that is defined in `modules.js`.  That would need code like this (slightly modified from the tutorial where most of this code originated):

```
User.getAuthenticated('<valid_email>', '<valid_password>', function(err, user, reason) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (user) {
            // handle login success
            // note, handling success is more than a res.redirect call
            // if you need to deal with session, state, cookies, etc...
            return;
        }

        // otherwise we can determine why we failed
        var reasons = User.failedLogin;
        switch (reason) {
            case reasons.NOT_FOUND:
            case reasons.PASSWORD_INCORRECT:
                // note: these cases are usually treated the same - don't tell
                // the user *why* the login failed, only that it did
                break;
            case reasons.MAX_ATTEMPTS:
                // send email or otherwise notify user that account is
                // temporarily locked
                break;
        }
    });
```

As a side-node, I'd suggest you look into everyauth or passport.js as modules that can do much of this for you.  At that point, your main concern will be writing code for user CRUD while the modules handle sessions, cookies, serialization/deserialization and so on for you.  This is doubly true if you have any plans to include OAUTH logins via google, facebook, et al.

Comment: However, it is not checking if it is a real account but just redirecting to the correct page...